# Why is vgg19 much slower than alexnet to train, 50 hours vs 4 hours respectively?

Tags: matlab, svm, feature-extraction, pre-trained-model, vgg-net

I'm trying to use pretrained model `vgg19` and `alexnet` as feature extractor then using `svm` for classification. I have about 15000 images as input data. I'm using a server hp proliant g7 but `vgg19` takes about 50h to train while `alexnet` only about 4h. Is this normal or I should look into some setup or data issue on my end for the `vgg19` case?

Comment: Do you expect a Yes \ No answer?

Comment: I need an explanation of this case

Answer (score 0):

Vgg19 is much bigger network than alexnet, if I remember correctly, around 12 times. What I suspect is that alexnet fits into memory without a problem but not vgg19. If MATLAB is out of memory during training it may start swapping memory with hard disc and that becomes painfully slow (instead of immediately crashing with out of memory message as Tensorflow does). I suggest reducing mini-batch size or trying out other networks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I said that I'm working on server hp proliant g7 windows server 2012 RAM 32GB and Intel Xeon cpu E5649, is it not enough to make vgg19 speed?  You suggest me to reduce mini-batch size ,what do you mean by "mini-batch"? and  how can I do it?